# Foobar2000 chrome interface improvement

Tags: foobar2000

I recently got into Foobar2000 and while I love most things about it, I'm rather disastisfied with the ugly scroll bars, separators, and look of the default interface. Is there a way I can change this without having to lose the default Interface Module?

(Columns-UI is more complicated and I don't really want to deal with it, if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word: No.  The Default UI Module, by and large, uses standard Windows widgets in a fairly sane manner.  If you want something vastly different, you're going to have to use either an alternate UI module or a different player.

That said, the Default UI module is pretty powerful, and some very attractive layouts have been built up using it.  The [Default UI Gallery](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=58574) and [Associated Discussion](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=58686) threads on the Foobar2000 forum may provide some insight.

Also, I haven't used them myself, but you may find the [SimPlaylist](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_simplaylist) and [SimPlaylist Manager](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_simplaylist_manager) components of some worth in letting you put together a UI you're happier with without as much complexity as the Columns UI might introduce for you.

Comment: It's worth noting that user's have managed to achieve a better looking with the Default UI using Visual Styles for Windows. And while that's not a direct solution, it's still helpful, as was the rest of your information. thanks!